# Python: Splitting a column into two Columns based off its value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get from My Starting DataFrame

[image: My Starting DataFrame]

to My Desired Results

[image: My Desired Results].

I am trying to do a groupby on two columns (Name, Month) and I have a column (Category) that has either the value 'Score1' or 'Score2'.  I want to create two columns with the name of values from the Category column and set their values to a value determined from another column.

```
pd.crosstab([df.Name, df.Month], df.Category)
```

is the closest I've got to create the desire data frame however I can't figure out how to get the values from my "Value" column to populate the dataframe.

Results from crosstab

[image: Results from crosstab]

The Dataframe in code form

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Month', 'Category', 'Value'])
df['Name'] = ['Jack','Jack','Sarah','Sarah','Zack']
df['Month'] = ['Jan.','Jan.','Feb.','Feb.','Feb.']
df['Category'] = ['Score1','Score2','Score1','Score2','Score1']
df['Value'] = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Providing your data as code would be more helpful than the images you have given and will help you get an answer to your question more quickly.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time on this site.  Did I do it correctly?

Comment: Looks much better, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Pivot Table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Name', 'Month'],values='Value', columns='Category').rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()

Out[1]: 
    Name Month  Score1  Score2
0   Jack  Jan.     1.0     2.0
1  Sarah  Feb.     3.0     4.0
2   Zack  Feb.     5.0     NaN
```

Comment: Is there a way to reverse the process?  Combining the 'Score1' and 'Score2' back into the Category Column and then setting the Value elements back?

Comment: @NathanLam `df.melt(id_vars=['Name','Month'], var_name='Category', value_name='Value')`

Answer (score 0):

one way is with `groupby` and `unstack`

```
new_df = (df.groupby(['Name','Month','Category'])
 ['Value'].first().unstack().reset_index())
print(new_df)
Category   Name Month  Score1  Score2
0          Jack  Jan.     1.0     2.0
1         Sarah  Feb.     3.0     4.0
2          Zack  Feb.     5.0     NaN
```